# How can I recreate an email folder from online web archives?

Tags: email, archiving, recovery, mailbox, webarchive

For reasons, I have misplaced a mail folder with a bunch of messages from a mailing list. Luckily - this list has an online archive:

https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/design/

is there any way to recreate a Mozilla [MBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) (more specifically, mboxrd) file out of these messages? i.e. other than writing my own program to download and convert them?

Comment: Do you just mean downloading all the messages? Does the mailing list have a feature to deliver old messages? If not, I'm guessing you're stuck downloading and importing these.

Comment: @music2myear: I mean either getting my mail client to download the messages - in which case it will store them; but more likely, some other method for downloading the messages en masse - as web pages - and constructing an mbox file from them. Which includes constructing headers.